# Accessing Head Voice From Vocal Fry

Tags: falsetto, vocal-cords, vocal-fry

Is it possible to access one's head voice by by using vocal fry?

Falsetto is known to have its vocal chords spread apart, resulting in a high pitched but airy and quiet tone. Head voice is also used to achieve high notes as well, but with compressed vocal cords, resulting in a more fuller sound.

After researching about vocal fry, I learned that even though the vocal cords are relaxed, they are still compressed and together. Vocal fry is used in several genres (e.g. RnB) and is utilized in the beginning of a phrase to give that "raspy" texture.

So referring to my question, by using vocal fry at the beginning of a phrase which involves high pitched notes, would that allow an individual to access head voice (due to the vocal cords being compressed at both moments) or will it default to falsetto?

Comment: Care for someone to explain why this is down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very confused question.  Your description of falsetto is mostly wrong, partly by mixing up cause, effect, and side effects.  Falsetto comes about by a particular configuration of the larynx that does make it harder to achieve good closure in lower ranges.  The fundamental pitch control mechanisms in falsetto and chest-based voices are considerably different in character.  Bottoming out the ranges of either falsetto or chest voice will end in a sort of vocal fry (it takes practice to stay in falsetto instead of flipping back into a chest register in the low range) characterized by rather loose vocal cords.  This fry is, however, achieved at different larynx configurations.

Pitch control in falsetto works by tensioning the vocal folds from their fixtures, with the muscles constituting the base of the folds relaxed.  Pitch control in chest based registers involves tensioning the muscles underlying the vocal folds themselves.  Either mechanism is reliable and fast enough to support coloratura singing.  So preconditioning the texture of the folds with pre-noise is not really buying you anything with regard to accessing different registers.

Piecing together parts of different descriptions and theories based on their choice of words is very likely to land you with something that only sounds like making sense.